# How to raise GET queries from Java application using Netty?

Tags: java, get, netty

I want to send a GET query to my server from a Java application. I am using Netty. Is there a straightforward documentation on how to do this? Like, how we do for HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: What is the framework you use ?

Comment: Maybe this site helps you https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop